# Google Tag Manager Preview: Tags Fired on Events, not showing in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up Google Tag Manager (GTM) with PageView and a submit button event on my site. When I use preview GTM mode on my site I can see the Tags being fired when I view the page and click the submit button (after filling out my contact form) however when I open Google Analaytics Real time, I am only seeing the PageViews and I have waited 24 hours.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us you tag configuration? Also make sure there are no filters and that you are checking the correct GA property.

Comment: @nyuen I fixed it, basically the problem was the set up. Silly me in tag config I did not choose the correct event tag type "Universal Analytics."